# Image background with 50% opacity overlay

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a new section on my website, something I haven't done before. I want to create a section with a full width background image. But the right side of the image need a 50% opacity color overlay. I found a example image showing exactly what I want to create:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssvI7.jpg

I have tried searching on Google for any tutorials, but the only things I find are full width images with full width opacity color overlay.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please provide code of what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you know how to overlap layers? Do you know how to set background images, background colors and layer's opacity? If you do, please think about the problem and you'll find a solution. It's an easy one. If not, start by learning this topics.

Comment: firs of all put some html and css you're using, and better, a fiddle of what you've tried. Then we can help you achieving what you want. Without any code it is not possible.

Comment: yea as suggested by @Jordi, start studying background-size and div absolutely positioned as overlays.

Comment: Are you coding this yourself or in some kind of editor? How much of the structure of the site can you change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

#opacity_div {
  background: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 30%;
  opacity: 0.5/* manipulate to desired opacity */
}

img.half_fade {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="opacity_div"></div>
  <img class="half_fade" src="https://hindi.oneindia.com/img/2017/10/68-28-1477651101-02-1506944733.jpg" width="70%">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest giving the overlay an absolute value (position: absolute) and then starting it halfway across the page by giving it a left value of (left: 50%)

You can then give the overlay a whatever colour/opacity you like

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this is helpful to you. here you can use before and after psuedo elements.

```css
div {
background:url('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff') no-repeat top center;
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
}

div:before, div:after {
content:'';
width: 50%;
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
display:block;
z-index:1;
}

div:before{left:0; background: rgba(255,255,255,.8);}

div:after{right:0; background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just edit the background image to have the overlay already on it if you are not able to code it up yourself. However, this approach won't really work if your website is responsive.